# Watir command to attach browser window does not work in radrails ide

Tags: watir, title, radrails

I use the radrails ide for running watir tests. I have the following command:

```
ie.link(:text, "Task").click
ie1=Watir::IE.attach(:title, 'Task')
```

Using the above command I get the error:

```
E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/ie-class.rb:760:in `rescue in attach_browser_window': Unable to locate a window with title of Task (Watir::Exception::NoMatchingWindowFoundException)
    from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/ie-class.rb:755:in `attach_browser_window'
    from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/ie-class.rb:157:in `_attach_init'
    from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/ie-class.rb:151:in `attach'
    from file.rb:31:in `<main>'
```

The Ruby version is 1.9.3, ie 8, html code of the page I want to attach -

```
<a id="sdmenu141" class="nodeSel" onclick="javascript: dmenu.s(141);" target="_self" href="javascript:configuredWindowOpen('../ROU/Mterou004p0001Form.do?resetFilter_‌​‌​action=','_blank','regular');">Task</a>
```

after clicking on the link in the first line of code it opens new browser window.

Also today I got a new error:

```
E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/ie-cla‌​ss.rb:374:in method_missing': (in OLE method navigate': ) 
(WIN32OLERuntimeError) OLE error code:800700AA in <Unknown> <No Description> HRESULT error code:0x80020009
Exception occurred. from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/ie-cla‌​ss.rb:374:in goto' from file.rb:7:in <main>'
```

Comment: What is the exact title of the new window you're trying to attach to?

Comment: It is Task. I try reinstall ruby, now no errors. But will be gratfull if you told me the reason of this error

Comment: When you click the link in line 1, what happens? Does it actually open a new popup or is it one of those popup look a likes (ie is actually just something like a div tag)? Perhaps update the question with the HTML of what you are attaching to?

Comment: after clicking in line 1 new pop up is opened (like new browser window). This is html code

Comment: <a id="sdmenu141" class="nodeSel" onclick="javascript: dmenu.s(141);" target="_self" href="javascript:configuredWindowOpen('../ROU/Mterou004p0001Form.do?resetFilter_action=','_blank','regular');">Task</a>

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error message says it all: `Unable to locate a window with title of Task`.

Comment: Understand, but why, today i run test once again and get the same error, how can i solve this?

Comment: I do not know, you did not provide enough data.

Comment: ruby version is 1.9.3, ie 8, html code of page i want attach - <a id="sdmenu141" class="nodeSel" onclick="javascript: dmenu.s(141);" target="_self" href="javascript:configuredWindowOpen('../ROU/Mterou004p0001Form.do?resetFilter_‌​action=','_blank','regular');">Task</a>, after clicking on link (first line of code) opens new browser window, what addition data do you need to inspect problem?

Comment: Did you run the test from command line or from IDE (radrails)?

Comment: You have provided HTML that say the link that opens new window has text "Task". It does not mean that the title of the opened window will have the same title.

Comment: i run test from both - command line and IDE - once it works, once no, if i get error - it is in both (IDE and command line), i try attach window by its url also. How can i define window title?

Comment: Also today i get new error - E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/ie-class.rb:374:in `method_missing': (in OLE method `navigate': ) (WIN32OLERuntimeError)
    OLE error code:800700AA in <Unknown>
      <No Description>
    HRESULT error code:0x80020009
      Exception occurred.
 from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/ie-class.rb:374:in `goto'
 from file.rb:7:in `<main>'

Comment: If you have another problem, create new question.

Comment: Please see my previous comment: _You have provided HTML that say the link that opens new window has text "Task". It does not mean that the title of the opened window will have the same title._

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue use Watir Web Driver.